# maven plsql build fails :: Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:sql-maven-plugin:1.3:execute (create-schema) on project my-utplsql-tests

Tags: maven

My maven build fails with below error::

```
Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:sql-maven-plugin:1.3:execute (create-schema) on project my-utplsql-tests: Execution create-schema of goal org.codehaus.mojo:sql-maven-plugin:1.3:execute failed: Plugin org.codehaus.mojo:sql-maven-plugin:1.3 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to collect dependencies at org.codehaus.mojo:sql-maven-plugin:jar:1.3 -> com.oracle:ojd
bc6:jar:11.2.0:
```

Kindly help me.

My POM XML is as below.

```
<build>
        <plugins>

        <plugin>

            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>

            <artifactId>sql-maven-plugin</artifactId>

            <version>1.3</version>


            <dependencies>
      <!-- specify the dependent jdbc driver here -->

                <dependency>
                        <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
                        <artifactId>ojdbc14</artifactId>
                        <version>10.2.0.4.0</version>
                        </dependency>

            </dependencies>

    <!-- common configuration shared by all executions -->

            <configuration>

                <driver>oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</driver>

                <url>jdbc:oracle:thin:@${db.host}:1521:${db.instance}</url>

                <username>${db.username}</username>

                <password>${db.password}</password>          
                <delimiter>/</delimiter>

                <delimiterType>row</delimiterType>

                <keepFormat>true</keepFormat>

            </configuration>


            <executions>

                <execution>

                    <id>create-schema</id>

                    <phase>process-test-resources</phase>

                    <goals>

                        <goal>execute</goal>

                    </goals>

                    <configuration>

                        <orderFile>ascending</orderFile>

                        <delimiter>;</delimiter>

                        <delimiterType>normal</delimiterType>

                        <onError>continue</onError>

                        <keepFormat>false</keepFormat>

                        <fileset>

                        <basedir>src/main/sql</basedir>

                        <includes>

                            <include>**/*.sql</include>

                        </includes>

                        </fileset>

                    </configuration>

                </execution>



                <execution>

                    <id>create-plsql-packages</id>

                    <phase>process-test-resources</phase>

                    <goals>

                        <goal>execute</goal>

                    </goals>

                    <configuration>

                        <orderFile>ascending</orderFile>

                                <fileset>

                            <basedir>src/main/plsql</basedir>

                            <includes>

                                <include>**/*.pks</include>

                                <include>**/*.pkb</include>

                                <include>**/*.sf</include>

                            </includes>

                        </fileset>

                    </configuration>

                </execution>



                <execution>

                    <id>insert-data</id>

                    <phase>process-test-resources</phase>

                    <goals>

                        <goal>execute</goal>

                    </goals>

                    <configuration>

                        <orderFile>ascending</orderFile>

                        <delimiter>;</delimiter>

                        <delimiterType>normal</delimiterType>

                        <onError>continue</onError>

                        <keepFormat>false</keepFormat>

                        <fileset>

                            <basedir>src/main/resources/data</basedir>

                            <includes>

                                <include>**/*.sql</include>

                            </includes>

                        </fileset>

                    </configuration>

                </execution>



                <execution>

                    <id>create-plsql-test-packages</id>

                    <phase>process-test-resources</phase>

                    <goals>

                        <goal>execute</goal>

                    </goals>

                    <configuration>

                        <orderFile>ascending</orderFile>

                        <fileset>

                            <basedir>src/test/plsql</basedir>

                            <includes>

                                <include>**/*.pks</include>

                                <include>**/*.pkb</include>

                                <include>**/*.sf</include>

                                <include>**/*.sp</include>

                            </includes>

                        </fileset>

                    </configuration>

                </execution> 


            </executions>

        </plugin>


        <plugin>

            <groupId>com.theserverlabs.maven.utplsql</groupId>

            <artifactId>maven-utplsql-plugin</artifactId>

            <version>1.31</version>


            <dependencies>

                <dependency>
                            <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
                            <artifactId>ojdbc14</artifactId>
                            <version>10.2.0.4.0</version>
                        </dependency>

            </dependencies>


            <configuration>

                <driver>oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</driver>

                <url>jdbc:oracle:thin:@${db.host}:1521:${db.instance}</url>

                <username>${db.username}</username>

                <password>${db.password}</password>          
                <!--<packageName>betwnstr</packageName>-->

                <testSuiteName>All</testSuiteName>

            </configuration>

            <executions>

                <execution>

                    <id>run-plsql-test-packages</id>

                    <phase>process-test-resources</phase>

                    <goals>

                        <goal>execute</goal>

                    </goals>

                </execution>

            </executions>

        </plugin>


    </plugins>

</build>
```

Comment: The error is: failed to download `com.oracle:ojdbc6:jar:11.2.0`. Given its name, it's expected since Oracle JDBC driver aren't publicly available. So you need to install it by hand or use a repository manager.

Comment: I had installed it using below command.                    mvn install:install-file -Dfile=ojdbc6.jar -DgroupId=com.oracle -DartifactId=ojdbc6 -Dversion=11.2.0.2.0 -Dpackaging . I tried with same version in POM file however no luck. In https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/oracle ojdbc14 is available having version 10.2.0.4.0.

Comment: Thank you - I have downloaded 10g odbc jar and able to come over this error.